# Bundler/Rubygems not working on Gogo Inflight wifi

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm currently using Gogo inflight wifi, and I'm unable to run bundle install.  It hangs when connecting to rubygems.

After running `bundle install`, it simply hangs at
`Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/`

When I ping rubygems.org, I get 100% packet loss, so I am guessing Gogo blocks all icmp traffic to this domain.

I contacted Gogo support and they gave me the following response(which shows that the person didn't understand what I was talking about):

> Areli: As a good partner to our airline customers, if asked, Gogo will work with them to implement such content filtering technology and policies as they deem appropriate to ensure the best possible Inflight Internet experience for their passengers.  For more information, you will need to speak with the airlines, themselves.
>
> We understand that in doing so, some websites may inadvertently be flagged as inappropriate. We appreciate your letting us know this has occurred and will take appropriate steps to enable our customers to visit this site.
> I'm curious if anyone has ever had this problem, had any insight, tips or tricks.

Thanks!

Comment: you must be in a super slow connection!

Comment: although it is slow, I don't think it would entirely explain the problem.  I suspect they are manipulating the traffic in some way.